# Is this the correct definition for the phrase "go on" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I'm watching a show and one of the characters is shopping with his wife and a kid when he is approached by two police officers and asked to go to talk with them somewhere in private. His wife asks him if everything is alright and he answers **"It's ok dear, go on home"**.

Macmillan dictionary definition for "go on" INTRANSITIVE:

> to go to a place before someone else who you are with
> *Why don’t you go on without me?*

I ask because I've read a couple of threads on different forums where people said **"go on home"** is only a more polite way to say **"go home"**.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was necessarily 'more polite'. It's used here exactly as your definition says. Presumably they would all have gone home after the shopping trip; he is telling his wife and child to go there without him.

Comment: Yes, Kate I think this definition definitely applies here especially that later he says that he says to her "I'll see you at home"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "go on home" can simply mean "go home". Here is [Macmillan's definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/go-on):

> to go to another place after going somewhere

For example, if you're at a bar and have had too much to drink, the bartender can tell you to "go on home".

By the way, it is hard to convey all of the meanings of a phrase like this in a short dictionary entry. (Macmillan's definition isn't very good, in my opinion. After all, you've *always* gone somewhere.) Here is [the relevant definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20on):

> 1a: to continue on or as if on a journey
> b: to keep on : CONTINUE
> c: PROCEED

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your edit of the question and your answer! Thank you very much for correcting me when I write something wrong! Thank you very much for helping me!